# C++ Linked list and sum issue

Tags: c++

I keep getting an error with the code below and I don't know why.

```
int sum(struct node *head)
{
    int total = 0;
    struct node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        total += temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
```

> Error C4716   'sum': must return a value

Comment: Because `sum` promises to return an `int` but does not. A `return total;` at the end of the function is probably in order. I suspect a function with a name like `sum` should return the calculated sum, and you went through all the trouble of computing it.

Comment: You know, I was about to complain the function doesn't have a closing bracket when I noticed that `}}`. That's a poor way to place a curly brace, it gets lost in the jumble of code and *doesn't* indicate where a function ends. I suggest you give up this style asap, because it will make collaborating with other developers harder.

Answer (score 3):

Just like the the error message is saying, you need a `return` statment:

```
int sum(struct node *head)
{
    int total = 0;
    struct node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        //cout << temp->data << '\n';    //debug
        total += temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return total; // <-- add this!
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As you write `int sum(struct node *head)` that means your funtion should return a integer value. So what you can do is that you can add a return statement at the end of your funtion.

Something like that

```
    int sum(struct node *head)
    {
    int total = 0;
    struct node *temp = head;
    while (temp != NULL)
    {
        total += temp->data;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
    return total;
    }
```

And the statement where you call this function just assign that function to any integer variable.

```
int t = sum(head);
```

Hopefully that helps

Comment: `int t = sum(*head);` may be a guess too far. Odds are good that `head` would not need to be dereferenced.

Comment: If their is any sort of error or mistake you can edit it sir